# Is there any way to store a set of preset input values in tradingview or using pinescript？

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

```
a = input.bool(defval = false, title="a")
b = input.int(defval = 1, title="b")
c = input.float(defval = 0.5, title="c")
```

I have some input form values, they are not same in different symbol/timeframe charts. Every time i switch between different charts, i have to change the input values.
Is there any way to store a set of preset values in tradingview, or make use of pinescript to decalre them, then reassign to a/b/c?

I have tried to write the code but something went wrong.

```
symbol_input = input.string('BTC', title="preset", options = ['BTC','ETH'])

// use to generate different input according to different symbol
params_gen() =>
    if symbol_input == 'BTC'
        [false, 1, 0.5]
    if symbol_input == 'ETH'
        [true, 2, 0.6]

[p1, p2, p3] = params_gen()
a = input.bool(defval = p1, title="a")
b = input.int(defval = p2, title="b")
c = input.float(defval = p3, title="c")
```

The above code will result in type error, so i want to know is there any way to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this so that pine automatically reassigns the values

```
a = input.bool(false)
b = input.int(1)
c = input.float(0.5)

get_sym = syminfo.ticker

if get_sym == 'BTC'
    b := 1, c:= .5
if get_sym == 'ETH'
    a := true, b := 2, c :=  0.6
```